# Get Mobile Number from iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Am I able to get the user's mobile number of the iPhone device? (of cause without asking the user for this information)

Comment: Why don't you want to let the user know you're using this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Apple's APIs do not provide access to this information. What's more, attempting to get this information without asking the user is generally considered a huge breach of privacy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to look it up in the address book if you know who the user is.  Otherwise, yeah, the easiest thing to do is ask the user to enter it and store it as a preference.