# How do I show a phone number by default in the text field on the register page in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

How do I show a phone number by default in the text field on the register page in iPhone?

Comment: Another [SO Post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129966/get-mobile-number-from-iphone).

Answer (score 1):

Can't.  Sorry.  Apple won't let you access a phone's number.  Best you can do is get the UUID device identifier.

If the user does input his phone number at some point, you can store and remember it, then pre-populate it for future forms, but you have no way of knowing that it's his real phone number for that device.

Comment: @user853528 If this has answered your quesiton, please accept it using the tick on the left - It prevents others coming here and trying to answer a question you've already solved.